# Keep directory and all subdirectories recursively except files

Tags: git, gitignore

I have an uploads folder in my project that I need git to track.
Both the folder itself and all subfolders (I mean

uploads,
  uploads/users,
  uploads/users/profiles,
  uploads/users/profiles/pics

and other paths like those) should be tracked.

I have added an empty file named `.gitkeep` to all folders and my `.gitignore` is as follows:

```
uploads/*
!.gitkeep
```

but git is not tracking the subfolders.

===============================================================

After CodeWizard suggestion for creating .gitkeep files via command and no solution to force git to ignore all files in a directory and childs except the ones having .gitkeep file. i used this command to git-add -f all .gitkeep files created under uploads directory.

```
find . -name '.gitkeep' | xargs git add -f
```

Comment: did you just create the .gitkeep files or also add them to git? whats' the output of `git status`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/26189082/1256452 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5533050/1256452

Answer (score 4):

Add `.gitkeep` to all your required folders.
Otherwize git will not track the folders

---

## Script to create `.gitkeep` recursively

```
# find all the directories (-type d)
# filter the empty ones (-empty)
# ignore the .git folder
# add .gitkeep to all the matched folders

find . -type d -empty -not -path "./.git/*" -exec touch {}/.gitkeep \;
```

---

If you want you can also add it to the **most inner folder** and git will track all the parent folders as well when **add** it to the index

The last line (sub1/sub2...) is the output of the above script

[image]

Comment: Your solution doesn't seem to work with the OP's `.gitignore`. It needs to be modified as follows: `uploads/** \n !uploads/users \n !uploads/users/profiles \n !uploads/users/profiles/pics`

Comment: Im sorry but i don't understand you. What is the problem with the script? i have tested it and its generating the output as seen in the screenshot

Comment: The problem is, at least on my system, it only tracks the outermost `.gitkeep`, i.e. `uploads/.gitkeep`, _if_ OP's `.gitignore` is used. That's why the `.gitignore` must be modified as well.

Comment: Yep, this is what it should do. when you check out the branch it will create the full folder structure. It generate `.gitkeep` in the inner most folder. This is enough to keep track of the folders

Comment: The problem with this example is `upload` (singular) vs `uploads` (plural).

Answer (score 1):

While CodeWizard's solution allows you to track the folders, it doesn't help you to ignore their file contents.

To do that, you need to modify your `.gitignore` to exclude each subfolder from being ignored. For instance:

```
uploads/**
!uploads/users
!uploads/users/profiles
!uploads/users/profiles/pics
```

You still need the `.gitkeep` files inside every subfolder, or at least inside the innermost subfolders. The command suggested by CodeWizard does an excellent job:

```
find . -type d -empty -not -path "./.git/*" -exec touch {}/.gitkeep \;
```

Comment: adding all sub folders manually is not my type, CodeWizard command is very useful but it would be great if it add -f the created .gitkeep too.